# Why does a compilation to certain Windows CE target get "skipped" in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I'm puzzled.

"0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 skipped" is what Visual Studio says to me if I try to compile a project to another target than what I normally work with.

My normal is Windows CE 5.0 SH4 physical device. What I try to also compile is i.e. Windows Mobile 6.0 Professional ARM (so I could run on an emulator which the SH4 target does not allow me to do).

What the h*ll is "skipped"? Where do I "unskip" the target?

Answer (score 1):

Seems I had removed the SDK packages in question. The VS IDE does not say so (which it could) but "skips" and/or gives linker errors, based on how nearly compatible SDKs are remaining on the system. Bummer.

Easy fix: remove the faulty configuration target and create new from the ones that do remain on the system.

Comment: Sorry to approve my own answer, but I do think this deserves to be mentioned somewhere. Never found anything matching on Google (and eventually I will forget about this and bang my head on it again in, say, 2013). :)